# How to categorize test classes and test methods and select specific categories for testing in nunit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, nunit

Is it possible to **categorize** test classes or test methods for example lets say as BASIC,PERFORMANCE and SIMPLE in **nunit** and then allow the user to decide which category of tests he wants to run. 
[Can the nunit extensions help in this in anyway?](http://nunit.org/docs/2.5/nunitAddins.html)
An explanation with an example will be highly appreciable.
PS: i am currently using nunit 2.6.4

Comment: You can use `CategoryAttribute` for classes or methods. Then based on test runner you will be able to execute particular category tests

Comment: @Fabio could you share an example on the same. I am currently using nunit 2.6.4 as test runner.

Comment: By test runners I mean their GUI. For examples Resharper and Test Explorer have feature to execute tests by `CategoryAttribute`. If you want achieve this for actual test runners - then separated different categories in different classes/files/projects will give possibility to execute them separately through command-line

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can categorize tests on either the class or the test level, and tests can have multiple categories as well.

One option as mentioned is the `[TestCategory("MyCategory")]` route, but I prefer to just create new attributes so i can have a more "strongly" typed set of categories to choose from.

Example:

```
public class FastIntegrationTestAttribute : CategoryAttribute { }

public class LongRunningIntegrationTestAttribute : CategoryAttribute { }

public class NightlyTestAttribute : CategoryAttribute { }
```

In action:

```
[TestFixture, FastIntegrationTest]
public class MyClassThatNeedsTesting
{

    [Test]
    [NightlyTest]
    public void MyTest()
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void AnotherTest()
    {
    }
}
```

Note that the fixture level attribute applies that attribute to all tests, so `MyTest` has both a "FastIntegrationTest" and "NightlyTest" attribute, where the `AnotherTest` just has the "FastIntegrationTest" attribute.

There are various ways to run specific categories of test, depending on your runner, and framework version.

in dotnetcore as an example, you can do:

```
dotnet test --where "cat == NightlyTest"
```

The resharper test runner also allows grouping by category,  in addition to the methods @Charlie mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You apply categories to tests or fixtures using the `CategoryAttribute`.

Then, you can run them in various ways, depending on the runner you use. For example...

- NUnit 2.6.4 console runner - use the `/include` and/or `/exclude` options on the command-line.
- NUnit 2.6.4 GUI runner - select the categories to run in the gui
- NUnit VS adapter running on Visual Studio - sort tests by trait and select the category that you want to run.

Comment: I tried to add the test category attribute in my test according to the   [procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx)given. But then it says "The type or namespace TestCategoryAttribute could not be found are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference". please help.here is my code snippet:[TestCategory("Nightly")]
        [Test]
        public void positivetest()
        {
            int x = 7;
            int y = 7;
            Assert.AreEqual(x, y);
        }

Comment: You are using NUnit but the documentation you are looking at is for MSTest. NUnit has `CategoryAttribute` not `TestCategoryAttribute`. See https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Category-Attribute